# Do we say "She looks prettier with her naked face" or "She looks prettier with her bare face"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I want to express a woman looks prettier if she does not wear any makeup on her face.

Are "**bare face**" and "**naked face**" the same?

For example, "**She looks prettier with her naked face**" or "**She looks prettier with her bare face**".

Update: The *Cambridge Dictionary* says

> [barefaced](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barefaced) adjective (WITHOUT MAKE-UP): not wearing any make-up (=
> coloured substances used on your face to improve or change your
> appearance):
>
> *She still looks like a teenager when she's barefaced and ponytailed. I prefer a barefaced, natural look.*

The Merriam-Webster dictionary says

> [barefaced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barefaced) adjective
>
> Synonyms of barefaced
>
> 1: having the face uncovered:
>
> a: having no whiskers : BEARDLESS
>
> b: wearing no mask

So, "**barefaced**" is not wearing a mask or makeup or both?

Let's say there are three women:

- the first is wearing make-up but not a mask
- the second is wearing a mask but not make-up
- and the third is wearing make-up and a mask

**Which woman is barefaced?**

Comment: No.  **She looks better without make-up.**  Barefaced means without a face covering however this meaning is fairly old fashioned, archaic. Today the word barefaced mainly has a very negative meaning, as in "barefaced lie" - which means shameless, impudent.  Don't use this term or you will most likely be misunderstood.  Also "naked face" is not something used in English.

Comment: Tom, there's a reason the word is "barefaced", not the phrase "bare face".

Comment: @Fattie 1. [Research explains the psychology of **going barefaced**.](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-clarity/201707/why-more-women-are-happily-going-without-makeup) 2. [While **going barefaced** has its perks, keeping your skin's health at the forefront is a must.](https://www.byrdie.com/real-women-no-makeup)  3. [I recently had a moment where I realized just how much power and confidence can come from **going barefaced**.](https://tz.linkedin.com/posts/firdosh-sheikh_selflove-barefacedandbeautiful-barefaced-activity-7007394230788603905-JLt2)

Comment: 4. [Discover why these women are going makeup free and embracing **barefaced beauty**](https://www.calmmoment.com/wellbeing/discover-why-these-women-are-going-makeup-free-and-embracing-barefaced-beauty/) 5. [This **barefaced beauty queen** is the first Miss England finalist to go makeup-free](https://www.insider.com/miss-england-finalist-made-history-after-competing-without-makeup-2022-8) 6. [I’m 35 and I wear makeup most days as makeup brings me joy and …. Having said that, … I love my **bare face**. I am **barefaced** around 40% of the time.](https://www.mamamia.com.au/no-makeup-selfies/)

Comment: @Fattie I think between your statements and CD *you* are the one who is utterly [**utterly, utterly, utterly wrong**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335304/do-we-say-she-looks-prettier-with-her-naked-face-or-she-looks-prettier-with-h#comment637240_335306) and [**completely wrong**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335304/do-we-say-she-looks-prettier-with-her-naked-face-or-she-looks-prettier-with-h#comment637269_335304). You should know better, and you repeat this often enough across Stack Exchange, English is "incredibly" flexible.

Comment: ML, in very specific contexts (eg where maekup is being discussed) you could use that term.  For example, "raw" can be / is similarly used that way - in that context when you're already talking about makeup.

Comment: @Fattie Will you admit that CD was not utterly, utterly, utterly wrong? Because I can dig up other examples of *barefaced* and *bare face* written by English speaking women and men, if you like? I don't think  "raw" is comparable to "bare face", it suggests that the delicate epidermis has been scrubbed until it appears to be red or even bleeding. I'd prefer saying the "natural look" or "fresh faced"  which is *acqua sapone* (soap and water) in Italian.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, they aren't the same. Your first sentence (with "naked") would be unnatural. Your second sentence (with "bare") is possible but would still be very uncommon. In general, we use "bare" instead of "naked" for a specific part of the body. For example, someone might have a bare neck but not a naked neck.

The most common way of saying this (at least in AmE) would be what you said in your first sentence:

> She looks prettier without any makeup.

(Or something very similar to that.)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22naked+face%22&sxsrf=APwXEddnrcdRZfzOgLdD7He-vwBRohOuxg:1681444942269&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu6vjDvqj-AhWNNN4KHWWOA0wQ_AUoAHoECAEQCg&biw=1167&bih=609&dpr=1.56

Google Books show many examples for example "**The naked face of the Arab woman**"

Comment: In Arabic culture, women wear veils in public.  That book title relates to "not wearing a veil" rather than not wearing makeup.

Comment: See [these definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barefaced) for the adjective _barefaced_.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I said "in general". There are certainly some situations in which you could apply "naked" to a specific body part. It is often used to emphasize the lack of a covering, for example: "My finger felt naked without my wedding ring." In general, though, to say that a body part is uncovered in a neutral way, "bare" is preferred, at least in AmE.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Also the usual ways of saying it in BrE, both "without makeup" in your answer and "bare" in your comment.

Comment: @KateBunting, so we use the adjective/adverb "**barefaced**" for faces that do not wear any make-up or faces that do not wear a mask. The Cambridge dictionary says "**barefaced adjective: not wearing any make-up**". A woman is wearing a mask right now, but not wearing any make-up, can we say that "**woman is barefaced**"?

Comment: Also, "with her naked/bare face" sounds grammatically odd. "with her face naked/bare" sounds (grammatically) better. IMHO. (Of course, "without makup" sounds much better and natural, and is more precise.)

Comment: "so we use the adjective/adverb "barefaced" for faces that do not wear any make-up or faces that do not wear a mask"  That is **utterly incorrect**.  "Barefaced" has no relationship, in any way, whatsoever, to make-up.

Comment: Tom, you are extremely off-track here.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Tom, I think most people would understand _barefaced_ (in its literal sense) as meaning that the features are visible - not covered by a veil, mask or beard. I don't think it would be understood to mean 'wearing no makeup' **unless** the context was obviously a discussion on whether or not to wear it.

Comment: If a woman is wearing a mask, she is not barefaced. If you would try and listen to the native speakers you are asking questions of, you might learn something. It would be great6 of this OP would stop arguing with us and try to understand what is being said to him.

Comment: @KateBunting, a native English speaker said "**Anyone wearing make-up is not barefaced.**". If you say  "**a barefaced person is not wearing a mask or veil**", then you can also not say "**a person wearing make-up is barefaced**" right.

Comment: @Tom I know of no one who would understand what you were trying to say if you phrased it that way.  If it was already established you were talking about makeup (or masks, veils, tattoos, or whatever) you might still be understood using the phrase bare face but it would still sound unnatural. Even then but you would still not be able to get away with saying naked face.- North America

Comment: Part of the issue is that bare faced is too vague for useful communication without establishing context *ahead of time*. The problem with your two previous examples fail to establish context ahead of time and that they try to redefine this broad term to only mean something very specific.

Comment: Your two sentences leave a similar impression to this one: "*Anyone who is a woman has long hair.*" and "*A person with long hair is a woman.*" Clearly the logic here is wrong because long hair does not define a woman just like how makeup is not the only factor in making a face bare. It sounds unnatural because the meaning of the words do not align.

Comment: "Anyone wearing make-up is not barefaced" **only** in the context of talking about make-up.

Comment: For "not wearing a veil" (or mask), I would say "uncovered face" myself.

Comment: @Tom Barefaced just isn't a very common term to use at all. Without context, people won't know if you mean "no makeup" or "no mask." It would be better to just say "without makeup" or "uncovered" (if they aren't wearing a mask or veil).

Answer (score 7):

The answers and comments saying that "barefaced" can't mean "without makeup" are incorrect. It may not be common in their personal varieties on English, but it definitely is one sense of the word:

> The Jersey Girl star proves she's a natural knockout when she's caught bare-faced outside her New York home in July. [people.com (2004)](https://people.com/celebrity/natural-or-not-2/#:%7E:text=The%20Jersey%20Girl%20star%20proves%20she%27s%20a%20natural%20knockout%20when%20she%27s%20caught%20bare%2Dfaced%20outside%20her%20New%20York%20home%20in%20July.)

> Lily Allen goes for barefaced chic during Paris Fashion Week - just how flawless is her complexion?! [glamourmagazine.co.uk (2009)](https://www.glamourmagazine.co.uk/gallery/celebrities-without-makeup#:%7E:text=Lily%20Allen%20goes%20for%20barefaced%20chic%20during%20Paris%20Fashion%20Week%20%2D%20just%20how%20flawless%20is%20her%20complexion%3F!)

> The no-makeup movement has been gaining considerable attention in recent years, especially after singer Alicia Keys penned an essay about why she’s going barefaced. [washingtonpost.com (2016)](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-entertainment/wp/2016/11/29/pirelli-calendar-continues-the-no-makeup-movement-by-featuring-barefaced-actresses/)

> These 28 bare-faced celebrity selfies are ultimate skin goals [businessinsider.com (2018)](https://www.businessinsider.com/these-28-bare-faced-celebrity-selfies-are-ultimate-skin-goals-2018-2)

> The actresses posed for a barefaced picture with artist Alexandra Grant after attending a makeup-free dinner party thrown by Goop, Paltrow's own lifestyle brand. [people.com (2021)](https://people.com/style/celebrities-without-makeup-photos/#:%7E:text=The%20actresses%20posed%20for%20a%20barefaced%20picture%20with%20artist%20Alexandra%20Grant%20after%20attending%20a%20makeup%2Dfree%20dinner%20party%20thrown%20by%20Goop%2C%20Paltrow%27s%20own%20lifestyle%20brand.)

> 10 Female K-Pop Idols Who Look The Most Beautiful Barefaced [kpopmap.com (2022)](https://www.kpopmap.com/10-female-kpop-idols-who-look-the-most-beautiful-barefaced/)

> As Lady Gaga shocks with her beautiful bare-faced performance at this year’s Oscars, and Selena Gomez turns to #nomakeup selfies at the height of drama with Hailey Bieber, we can’t help but wonder, is bare-faced beauty the new Bold Glam? [bodyandsoul.com.au (2023)](https://www.bodyandsoul.com.au/beauty/barefaced-beauty-is-having-a-moment-and-the-stars-are-leading-the-charge/news-story/dc39f51856a4fcd77b4a0b8826a97486)

> Lady Gaga Goes Barefaced At Oscars – Why Do We Care? [roarnews.co.uk (2023)](https://roarnews.co.uk/2023/lady-gaga-goes-barefaced-at-oscars-why-do-we-care/)

This is just a small sample of uses, which shows it is used in both US and Commonwealth English, and it has a fairly long history of use. 2004 was the earliest I found with a quick Google search but I wouldn't be surprised if it goes back considerably further than that. It seems to be hyphenated about half the time now, with hyphenated being more common in earlier uses.

I wonder if it began as [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese), and has only more recently been adopted into more common use? Some of these examples only use the word in their headlines or captions, using other phrases in the body text.

But note that this use does seem limited to "barefaced" or "bare-faced". "She looks prettier with her bare face" does not seem like a natural sentence to me. In other words, it should be used as an adjective, not as a noun phrase.

Comment: Good response +1. As for "Lady Gaga goes barefaced", "why do we care" indeed

Comment: +1 and I think it's because better suited to EL&U. Perhaps one day?  I too noticed that *barefaced* is used in titles but not exclusively, see my comments beneath the OP.

Comment: >> saying "'barefaced' can't mean 'without makeup' are incorrect."  Do you not mean **utterly, utterly incorrect**?     :-D

Answer (score 3):

In this context, I (American native speaker) might say, “her natural face.”

“Her naked face” doesn’t sound idiomatic to me (although I could see it in some of the examples others have brought up, talking about a woman whose culture expects her to be veiled for modesty) and “bare-faced,” while it works, is an uncommon phrase with negative connotations.

A quick search through Google Books shows that the other top hits for “bare-faced” either are variations on “bare-faced liar” (such as calling a cult leader a *Bare-Faced Messiah*), a similar pejorative usage meaning *open and shameless*, such as “bare-faced adultery” or “bare-faced outrage” (referring to a public lynching), a reference to child soldiers too young to grow beards, and several jokes about naked people that used it as a more-polite substitution for “bare-assed.”

Answer (score 2):

> So, "**barefaced**" is not wearing a mask or makeup or both?

Note that the M-W entry you linked doesn't even mention the "without makeup" definition.  Neither does [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/barefaced).  Or the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/barefaced).  Or the [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/barefaced).

That only the Cambridge (not Oxford) entry lists the "without makeup" definition (and lists it second / last) should be taken as a sign that that usage is rare or niche.  I can in fact imagine a couple of niches where such usage might be known, but if your objective is to communicate effectively to a general audience, then you should use "barefaced" only in the sense of

1. **not wearing any kind of face-covering *garment*, such as a mask or veil**, or
2. open / unconcealed or exhibiting a lack of shame or scruples. [The second definition in the M-W entry you linked].

If you use it to mean "without makeup" then some people may understand you from context, but most will find your word choice odd.  The normal word choice is, in fact, "without makeup" or "without any makeup".

> Are "**bare face**" and "**naked face**" the same?

"Bare" and "naked" are related, but not the same or interchangeable.  Idiomatic usages of these have little overlap.  Any native speaker choosing "naked face" does so with the intention of drawing attention via that unusual word choice, but they probably mean the same as "bare face" -- that is, a face that is not covered by a mask, veil, *etc*..

Furthermore, note well that although "with her bare face" is not inherently incorrect, what you actually want in that sentence is probably "with her face bare" or "barefaced" (and we're still talking about clothes, here).  The difference is subtle, but the first primes me to expect "prettier" to be a comparison with a different "she", whereas with the others I understand it to be a comparison with a different state of the same face.  I'm not prepared to generalize that.

> **Which woman is barefaced?**

Definitely not either of those wearing a mask.  Perhaps there are people who would say none of them, but most would say that the one with makeup but no mask is barefaced, in the physical sense.